# Web Application Login Authentication and Security Issue

Tags: java, spring, security, tomcat, authentication

I'm newbie Java developer, request for some advice or study materials regarding to web application (or web portal)'s public login authentication method and security issue on firewall...

Im involving with develop a CRM Lead Management System for Insurance System, I would like to learn up about how to build the Secure Authentication.

Develop environment:
Web server = tomcat
Framework = Spring, Hibernate...

Please help :) 
thanks!

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-security-tutorials/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned you are a newbie in Java so i would suggest you first start with a basic Login Authentication page and understand its flow. Later you can move to advance level of Authentication.

You can follow the below url for learning the Authentication and Authorization.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-sec2/j-sec2.html By IBM